# Dreamweaver Shows Red Line Near Script Tag In PHP File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is my code in product.php file where a red line is shown by dreamweaver editor when i try to add the constant path of my own which i define in my php configuration.php file. Here is the snapshot so you can understand properly.
[my product.php file snapshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2IMU.png)

```
<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#search_div').get(0).scrollIntoView();  
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_PATH;?>js/jssor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_PATH;?>js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
```

I tried but can't able to fix the error. Please, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post your code in question.

Comment: i did some rnd but couldn't find the result and i think it's a major issue for all dreamweaver users. it didn't cause any problem in the code but the red line really bothers :(

Comment: whats the error in console...!!

Comment: try this ... (function( $ ) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#search_div').get(0).scrollIntoView();  
    });
 })( jQuery );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your javascript tag's code with src attribute i.e with source file above the document.ready script and right after the php code where you call your header.php file like this

```
<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_PATH;?>js/jssor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_PATH;?>js/jssor.slider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#search_div').get(0).scrollIntoView();  
        });
</script>
```

When you write any **coded script tag** in the php file make sure that your **coded script tag** should be called below the **script tag** in which you call your javscript source file with php define constants.

Comment: problem is not with the console guys infact the problem is with the structure